# How can I check if a function returns a result in an "IF Else" statement

Tags: python, function

```
def checkwin():
    if checkcolumn(board) or checkdiagonal(board) or checkrow(board):
        print(f"The winner is {winner}")

def checktie(board):
    # If no blank spaces("-") check it is a tie
    global gamerunning
    if "-" not in board and :
        printboard(board)
        print("It is a tie!")
        gamerunning = False
```

I'm trying to add a statement after `and` in the function `checktie()` to see if the statement `"The winner is {winner}"` is posted then we should ignore the `checktie()` function.

I tried inserting a boolean value to `checkwin()` but can't call it in the `checktie()` function

Comment: Your functions aren't returning anything, so there is no point in checking if they do. Why not `return` the information that you need rather than just `print` it?

Comment: Have you tried using flag?

Comment: I haven't come across flag yet but ill defiantly look into it. Thank you! @SourabhBurse

Comment: Global variables are bad. It's not JavaScript. If you want to have some variables used by different methods - create a class, put those methods in this class and add variables to the class. So those variables can be used by all methods in the class.

Answer (score 1):

The function needs to actually return a result:

```
def checkwin():
    return checkcolumn(board) or checkdiagonal(board) or checkrow(board)
```

Then you could do:

```
if "-" not in board and not checkwin():
```

However, you may want to rework your script because I don't know why `checktie()` would call `checkwin()` when whatever code is calling `checktie()` could simply call `checkwin()` itself. For example:

```
if checkwin():
    print(f"The winner is {winner}")
    gamerunning = False
elif checktie(my_board):  # This would need to return a boolean too.
    print("It is a tie!")
    gamerunning = False
else:
    # Continue game
```

Comment: This makes a whole lot of sense! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use another variable to determine the result.

```
has_won = False

def checkwin():
    global has_won
    if checkcolumn(board) or checkdiagonal(board) or checkrow(board):
        print(f"The winner is {winner}")
        has_won = True

def checktie(board):
    # If no blank spaces("-") and no winner is declared, check it is a tie
    global gamerunning
    if "-" not in board and not has_won:
        printboard(board)
        print("It is a tie!")
        gamerunning = False
```